# for loop and if statement interaction is not working as expected?

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement

I am not sure how my code is skipping the first item in my list...

I have tried checking if value is the same as first item in list and tried to check index zero as well but both skip the first value.

I have been looking at this for a while. Am I missing something obvious?

Example using `enumerate` and checking the `index`.

```
def threaded_query(self):
    for ndex, query_key in enumerate(['Acct #', 'Results', 'Final Results', 'IPAccts']):
        if ndex == 0:
            write_to_table = pow_query_dict[query_key].format(self.login, self.value)
        else:
            write_to_table = pow_query_dict[query_key].format(self.login)

            conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}', host='myserver',
                                  database='myDB', trusted_connection='yes')
            with conn:
                try:
                    conn.autocommit = True
                    cursor = conn.cursor()
                    cursor.execute(write_to_table)
                    print('Committed {} data to SQL Server tables.'.format(query_key))
                except BaseException as e:
                    print('Query failed with Exception: {}'.format(e))
```

Example checking for the exact value of first item in list:

```
def threaded_query(self):
    for query_key in ['Acct #', 'Results', 'Final Results', 'IPAccts']:
        if query_key == 'Acct #':
            write_to_table = pow_query_dict[query_key].format(self.login, self.value)
        else:
            write_to_table = pow_query_dict[query_key].format(self.login)

            ...
```

Both Results:

```
Committed Results data to SQL Server tables.
Committed Final Results data to SQL Server tables.
Committed IPAccts data to SQL Server tables.
```

As you can see in the results it appears to completely skip the `Acct #` in the if statement.

Comment: There seems to be an extra indentation after last `write_to_table = pow..` line ?

Comment: @SeljukGülcan ah yep that's it. I knew it was something obvious... That's what happens when you stare at your code for way to long. Probably should have left and come back. Its annoying that for some reason when you work in PyCharm it changes indention from time to time when pasting stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `with` block is inside the `else`. It should be

```
def threaded_query(self):
    for ndex, query_key in enumerate(['Acct #', 'Results', 'Final Results', 'IPAccts']):
        if ndex == 0:
            write_to_table = pow_query_dict[query_key].format(self.login, self.value)
        else:
            write_to_table = pow_query_dict[query_key].format(self.login)

        conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}', host='myserver',
                                  database='myDB', trusted_connection='yes')
        with conn:
            try:
                conn.autocommit = True
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.execute(write_to_table)
                print('Committed {} data to SQL Server tables.'.format(query_key))
            except BaseException as e:
                print('Query failed with Exception: {}'.format(e))
```

Comment: ...and in the time I wrote this it's already solved in the comments!

Comment: I knew it had to be something obvious I was not seeing. Been working on my program for wayyy to long today.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Ah! it happens all the time with me too by working too much on the same thing. Thank god! we have SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, already posted an answer while I was writing this hah:

But your with needs to be outside the else block.